# Call to undefined function odbc_connect() centos 7

Tags: php, centos, odbc

I'm using centos 7, and I'm trying to connect my msql server database, I can connect using putty

```
+---------------------+
| Connected!          |
|                     |
|sql-statement        |
|help [tablename]     |
|quit                 |
|                     |
+---------------------+
```

But when I try to connect using my php code I get this error:

> Call to undefined function odbc_connect()

I could install freetds, freetdsdevel, remi, remi-repo, epel, unix-odbc,unixODBC-devel, php-odbc and I see them in putty, but I can't see them in my phpinfo file. Can anyone help me please? Thanks!

Comment: same issue here. it seems that the only option is to recompile PHP but that's a bit complex.... is there an so that can be enabled or something?

Comment: Have you solved this issue guys?

Answer (score 0):

For php -v :7.0.++

```
yum install centos-release-scl-rh

 yum install rh-php70-php-odbc
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to install `php_odbc` drivers either through the terminal or through whmCpanel.